# FTP: Cannot change permission or write to 1 directory via FTP client, but all others are OK

Tags: web-hosting, server, ftp, directory-listing

I have a site with loads of directories. They all work fine but one. I can read from this directory but I cannot delete files from within it or upload files to it. I cannot change its permissions either, though I can do this with literally every other directory on the server.

Does anyone know how I can fix this or what could be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the directory is not within the same user group as the ftp user and www-data account, more than likely its set as owner root.

You need to login via ssh and do a `chown www-data:www-data /full/path/to/the/directory` if you don't have ssh access ask your webhost.

Comment: Thanks! hmm is there anyway to change the files owner via cPanel or File Manager? My command lines not very strong...

Comment: It can't be done in Cpanels file manager and the only way I think you can do it is via ssh.